# How to read annotation which is declared over a Java object?

Tags: java, object, reflection, annotations

How to read annotation which is declared over an object.

For e.g

Annotation :

***AuthorInfo.java***

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface AuthorInfo {
    String author() default "Dushyant Kumar";
    String login() default "dushyantashu";
}
```

What I am trying to do :

***Book.java***

```
@Data
public class Book {
    private int serialNo;
    private String review;
}
```

***Main.java***

```
public class Main {

    @AuthorInfo (
            author = "Barry Allen",
            login = "theflash"
    )
    private static Book book = new Book();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showAnnotation(book);
    }

    private static void showAnnotation(Object object) {
        // How to get values of annotation declared over this object. 
    }
}
```

My usecase is to generate this generic `showAnnotation()` method, that's why param is `Object`. How to achieve this? From what I explored, I only got ways to read annotation if it's declared over a class, or declared over a member of a class. Isn't there a way where given an object, if some annotation is present over it can be read?

Thanks

Comment: Annotations are static information on types and members. They are not declared “over this object”. You can read it via `Main.class.getDeclaredField("book").getAnnotation(AuthorInfo.class)`, as it is a property of the *field*, not the `Book` instance. The same `Book` instance can be referenced by different fields having entirely different annotations.

Comment: @Holger This makes sense, so only way I could have different annotation values over the objects of same class is to have them as members of some other class. Is that right?

Comment: Since you annotate the fields, these fields can be in any class you want, including the same class as their declared type, i.e. you can have annotated fields of type `Book` within the class `Book`. Still, this isn’t an association with the referenced instance; multiple fields may refer to the same instance, or the fields can be `null`, it all doesn’t matter, the annotations are just a property of the fields. And where’s the sense in trying to carry instance specific data in an annotation? Why not declaring an ordinary `AuthorInfo` class and an ordinary member of that type within `Book`?

Comment: @Holger Thanks! I'm more inclined on using annotation because I need it to be used by a lot of other classes. By making it an ordinary class, I need to add these classes, which I should not be doing so because it's corresponding to a different business logic. So I had the option to either create something like map of this AuthorInfo and different classes, or annotation which can be defined over these classes, or a wrapper over these classes which will also contain AuthorInfo. Thanks, I think defining annotation on the class declaration makes much more sense.

Comment: It doesn’t make more sense than an ordinary object pointing to a `Book` instance and an `AuthorInfo` instance to establish the association (when you can’t change the `Book` class). Having to change the *code* to add another book to the application’s data is a design that isn’t even worth a discussion…

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try with `generics` and `reflection`. Assume the `Book` class is annotated with `AuthorInfo` like below:

```
@AuthorInfo(author = "Ram", login = "ram")
public class Book {

}
```

Suppose if you want to know whether `AuthorInfo` is present in the object of `Book`, you can do like below. This is straight forward solution to know whether specific annotation is present in an object.

```
public class TestAnnotation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book = new Book();
        showAnnotation(book);

    }

    private static <T> void showAnnotation(T t) {
        Class<? extends Object> aClass = t.getClass();
        if (aClass.isAnnotationPresent(AuthorInfo.class)) {
            System.out.println("AuthorInfo annotation present");
            AuthorInfo authorInfo = aClass.getAnnotation(AuthorInfo.class);
            System.out.println(authorInfo.author());
            System.out.println(authorInfo.login());
        }

    }
}
```

Suppose, if you want to know all annotations on that object, something like below helps:

```
 private static <T> void showAnnotation(T t) {
    Class<? extends Object> aClass = t.getClass();
    for (Annotation annotation : aClass.getAnnotations()) {
        System.out.println(annotation.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in a generic signature like `<T> void showAnnotation(T t)`. It offers no benefit over `void showAnnotation(Object t)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the object class and then explore it. Via Reflection you could get its fields and methods also, and check if any has annotations on it.

Comment: The object’s class is `Book` and this class has no annotations…

Comment: I see @Data. So where is the annotation? Annotations are static information, don't depend on instances.

Comment: That’s the inherent problem of the question. If all you have is a `Book` instance, there is no annotation in scope. Oh well, there is indeed `@Data`, which carries no information, but the question obviously is about the `@AuthorInfo` which is intended to be associated with a book, but annotation don’t work this way.

Comment: Ok, you can check for the given object if there's a field with the same class in your Main  class (or any other controlled scope). If there is, you can retrieve that field annotations, so any time you recieve a Book you will return the @AuthorInfo

If it works I can update my answer and even provide some example

Comment: Sure, but it’s a very bad design. It doesn’t protect you from errors, like having multiple fields referring to the same object, it requires an expensive search and is not extendable, as you have to change you application code to incorporate a new instance or update the data. A sole `HashMap`, mapping from instance to associated data, is superior *in all aspects* (assuming that just storing the data in the instance itself is not an option, for whatever reason).

Answer (score -1):

Annotations can be read using `Reflection API`. Like

```
Class<Main> clazz = Main.class;
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
for (Method method : methods) {
    Annotation[] annotation = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
}
for (Field field : fields) {
   //This will get @AuthorInfo annotation on book
    Annotation[] annotation = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
    //This will get @Data annotation on Book class
    Annotation[] annotationsOnFieldClass = field.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations();
}
clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
```